# Label is not floating upward after writing text in textbox

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I created a floating lable textbox in which onFocus and onBlur props are used of text box.
Everything working fine but one problem is coming that lable is not going upward after typing some text on the textbox. Following is my code:

```
export class FloatingLabelInput extends Component {
state = {
isFocused: false
};

render() {
const { label, ...props } = this.props;
const { isFocused } = this.state;
const labelStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  left: 0,
  top: !isFocused ? 18 : 0,
  fontSize: !isFocused ? 20 : 14,
  color: !isFocused ? "#000" : "#102657"
};
return (
  <View style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
    <Text style={labelStyle}>{label}</Text>
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      onBlur={(value) => {
        if (value.length!=0) {
          this.setState({ isFocused: false });
        } else {
          this.setState({ isFocused: true });
        }
      }}
      onFocus={(value) => {
        if (value.length!=0) {
          this.setState({ isFocused: true });
        }
        else{
          this.setState({ isFocused: false });
        }
      }}
    >
      {this.props.value}
    </TextInput>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: So add input or keypress event with same logic....

Comment: please elaborate ...

Comment: You have focus and blur events so if you want it to also work as the user is typing, than you would use input or keypress/keyup/keydown events

Answer (score 1):

Below is a floating TextInput that was inspired by an article online. (https://goshakkk.name/floating-label-input-rn-animated/)

**FloatingLabelInput.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Animated } from 'react-native';

export class FloatingLabelInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isFocused: false,
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._animatedLabelValue = new Animated.Value(this.props.value === '' ? 0 : 1);
  }

  handleFocus = () => this.setState({ isFocused: true });
  handleBlur = () => this.setState({ isFocused: false });

  componentDidUpdate() {
    Animated.timing(this._animatedLabelValue, {
      toValue: (this.state.isFocused || this.props.value !== '') ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 200,
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    const { label, ...props } = this.props; //Here is the text for the label
    const { isFocused } = this.state;
    const labelStyle = {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      top: this._animatedLabelValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [this.props.labelFontSize*0.67, -this.props.labelFontSize*0.05],
      }),
      fontSize: this._animatedLabelValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [this.props.labelFontSize, this.props.labelFontSize*0.7],
      }),
      color: this._animatedLabelValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['#aaa', '#000'],
      }),
      fontWeight: this.props.bold ? 'bold' : 'normal'
    }
    const containerStyle = {
      paddingTop: 18,
      marginTop: 20
    }
    return (
      <View style={{paddingTop: 18}}>
          <Animated.Text>
            {label}
          </Animated.Text>
          <TextInput
            {...props}
            onFocus={this.handleFocus}
            onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```